# Transfer Access DB to SQL Server DB using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis, sql-server-2012, database-migration

How can I transfer a full database from Access to SQL Server 2012 using SQL Server Integration Services?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this.

You need BIDS and just create a control flow and task flows with what you want to do.

SSIS is simple drag and drops for the most part

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the Import/Export wizard. Simply right click on a database in SQL Server, choose Tasks > Import Data. The wizard will walk you through the setup. At the end you can save the package which then can be edited in BIDS.