# Trasnfer multiple table from one databsse to another database using SSIS

Tags: ssis

Can somebody please help me to transfer around 15 tables from one database to another database. At present I can do this one by one using Data Flow task, but then I need to do this task 15 times which is very time consuming.

Comment: Use the Export wizard. Check my answer [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059976/transfer-access-db-to-sql-server-db-using-ssis/18073794#18073794

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use a task? Maybe [`tasks->export`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) is what you're looking for.
Otherwise you'll need to create separate blocks for each table or:

1. Create a variable of type `object`
2. `Script Task`: Add to your list all table names.
3. Iterate over this object variable with `For each` loop container
4. Inside the loop create a source from a variable. In this variable specify the connection dynamically depending on the current loop value.

Answer (score 1):

you can use SSIS package, select Transfer SQL server objects from SSIS toolbox , in Object specify the source and destination servers and database. for copyAllObjects make it false . ObjectToCopy select CopyAllTables true or make it false and pick from the list the table you want to copy.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for the answer to this, here's an alternative method:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXeEZsGmJrI

Short version: use the "Transfer SQL Server Objects Task" in SSIS.